# MySQL Query - Find dates within range by month and year

Tags: php, mysql

I have a calendar that displays events for a given month and year. Each event has a start time and end time in `DATETIME` fields.

```
$org = $_SESSION['org_id'];
$month = 5;
$year = 2013;
```

The following only retrieves events that start or end within the specified month/year:

```
SELECT * FROM events WHERE org='$org' AND 
    ((MONTH(time_start)='$month' AND YEAR(time_start)='$year') OR
    (MONTH(time_end)='$month' AND YEAR(time_end)='$year'))
```

It does NOT return events that start AND end outside of the specified month/year.

ex. `time_start='2013-04-07 12:00:00' time_end='2013-06-07 12:00:00'` - the event is not found in my May 2013 query.

**How do I select events that start, end, or crossover a given month/year?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM events 
WHERE org='$org' 
    AND time_start < '$year-$month-01 00:00:00' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH 
    AND time_end > '$year-$month-01 00:00:00'
;
```

If you are nice to mysql you can even cast the strings to dates, other databases like those things, but mysql is just happy with strings yet.

Comment: It is necessary in my SQL to have $month="05", so it might help to set $start = sprintf("%4d-%02d-01 00:00:00", $year,$month) inside php.

Answer (score 0):

Use [BETWEEN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between)

```
$event_date = date('Ymd',mktime(0,0,0,$month,1,$year));

SELECT * FROM events WHERE org='$org' AND date($event_date) BETWEEN time_start AND time_end;
```

This query search all the events that has that date in between.

Try this [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bb133d/1) to see my point.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm afraid that given he has only year and month your solution would kick out events from 2013-05-20 to 2013-05-25 for request of 05 / 2013

Comment: True @flaschenpost, the OP just provide the month and Year. But, $day could be a constant and it would work.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your `AND` -

```
((MONTH(time_start)<'$month' AND YEAR(time_start)<='$year') AND
      (MONTH(time_end)>'$month' AND YEAR(time_end)>='$year'))
```

So your query now becomes (a little clunky, but it should get you in the right direction) -

```
SELECT * FROM events WHERE org='$org' AND 
    (((MONTH(time_start)='$month' AND YEAR(time_start)='$year') OR
      (MONTH(time_end)='$month' AND YEAR(time_end)='$year')) 
     OR
     ((MONTH(time_start)<'$month' AND YEAR(time_start)<='$year') AND
      (MONTH(time_end)>'$month' AND YEAR(time_end)>='$year')))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$start = date('Y-m-d', mktime((0,0,0,$month,1,$year)));
$end = date('Y-m-d', mktime((23,59,59,$month+1,0,$year)))
```

And you need to check for four conditions:

- Event start date between $start and $end
- Evend end date between $start and $end
- $start between event start date and event end date
- $end between event start date and event end date

---

```
SELECT *
FROM events
WHERE org='$org'
AND ( (start_time BETWEEN '$start' AND '$end')
    OR (end_time BETWEEN '$start' AND '$end')
    OR ('$start' BETWEEN start_time AND end_time)
    OR ('$end' BETWEEN start_time AND end_time)
)
```

Comment: What do you need four cases for? If and only if event-start is before month-end and event-end is after month-start, both overlap.

Comment: True, my solution could be a bit overcomplicated. +1 for you.